# Skrollr. change content in fixed div

Tags: javascript, skrollr

I wonder how to achieve this effect on http://www.squarespace.com. What I mean is:

- you scroll down and at one point the image of computer monitor stays at fixed position
- after that, the images keep changing while you scroll.

How can you control content and change CSS using Javascript? It should be on window scroll event:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    // but I don't know what to use here
}
```

At smaller browser width, the above elements become a carousel, but I am not interested in that.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the tags on this post I'm going to assume that this question is regarding the [skrollr library](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)

Skrollr is controlled via HTML data attributes. What you're seeing when the monitor scrolls, and then becomes fixed at a given position, is referred to as "pinning". How you define data attributes in Skrollr can be pretty confusing at first, but once that is understood, the library is kind of a dream to work with.

I printed and pinned [Petr Tichy's cheat sheet](https://ihatetomatoes.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/skrollr-cheatsheet-v02.png) next to my monitor the first few weeks of my first skrollr project.

An example of pinning in Skroller would be accomplished as such:

```
<div id="example"
     data-100-top="position:fixed;"
     data-anchor-target="#example">

   These words are pinned 100px from the top of the screen      

</div>
```

The purpose of Skrollr is that knowledge of jQuery/JavaScript isn't really required. The css is manipulated by the library, and defied in the data elements. The above example shows changing the position to fixed, but if you wanted the div to expand 100px from the top you could input width/height css parameters in there, or just about any other css you'd like.

If you're looking for a more robust skrolling library, in which jQuery knowledge is more of a requirement, I recommend you take a look at ScrollMagic (my lack of reputation prevents me from linking to scrollmagic).